# Right click on nested component triggering twice react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mouseevent

I am using material ui's tree component which is a bunch of nested treeItem components. I would like to have a rightClick event trigger on each individual tree node. I use onContextMenu to do so, however, since my components are nested, when I right click an inner component the right click event triggers twice, once for the inner component I just right clicked and once for its parent component. Any ideas how I can stop this from occuring?

my code:

```
function Tree( props ) {

  // Recursively generate tree items passed to component
  const renderTree = ( nodes ) => (
    <TreeItem key = {nodes.id} nodeId = {nodes.id} label = {nodes.name} onContextMenu = {rightClick}>
      {Array.isArray( nodes.children ) ? nodes.children.map( (node) => renderTree(node) ) : null}
    </TreeItem>
  )

  const rightClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("LOL")
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <TreeView
      defaultCollapseIcon = {<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon = {<ChevronRightIcon />}
      multiSelect>
      {renderTree( props.treeItems )}
    </TreeView>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also stop the event bubbling up the DOM by stopping its propagation.

- [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)
- [Event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

> The **`stopPropagation()`** method of the `Event` interface prevents further
>   propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.
>   It does not, however, prevent any default behaviors from occurring;
>   for instance, clicks on links are still processed. If you want to stop
>   those behaviors, see the `preventDefault()` method.

```
const rightClick = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation()
  alert("LOL")
}
```